# Why the result of parseInt("123abcd") and parseInt("abcd123") are different in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

While was reading about NaN in JavaScript, I encountered with some examples. Then I started to test more and I got surprised by the results. For example I was wondering why JavaScript interpret the two below almost same statements differently

```
parseInt("123abcd") //  123
parseInt("abcd123") // NaN
```

Why javascript returns 123 for parseInt("123abcd") and why NaN for the other one?

Also why

```
isNaN("1") //false
But
isNaN("hello") // true -----> This seems logical because hello is a not number
```

It seems JavaScript can always surprise us!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first case

> [**MDN:**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)
>    If the first character cannot be converted to a number, parseInt returns NaN.

And for the second, `isNaN` converts the input to `Number` and then checks if it is a number or not.

So `"1"` is `1` and hence a number.

Also, it is worthy to know to use 10 as the radix to avoid any mis-interpretations.

```
parseInt(input, 10);
```

Comment: Still this leaves me with the question why the convention is to correctly parse a string starting with a number but not strings ending with a number. To me `parseInt` always looked arbitrarily. Why not parse the first number occurrence in the string (Eg. `"hello123Bye"`) ?

Comment: @Mouser that's how it's designed to be. It looks from the first. You can use a custom function to do what you want though.

Comment: @Mouser If your question is "Why is it like that?", ask Brendan Eich (I assume). Rather than expecting to parse any random digits it finds, I always wondered why they decided an invalid number like "123abcd" should be treated as valid. But I'll guess we'll never know...

Comment: @AmitJoki Yes I know. Like Rhumborl said. Why did they choose that particular behavior?

Comment: @Mouser parseInt does the parsing and parsing is mostly done left-right and hence the behavior, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

> If parseInt encounters a character that is not a numeral in the specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and returns the integer value parsed up to that point.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt